# error indexing global "self"?

Tags: c++, lua, love2d

I'm getting an error code that tells me that it "can't index local "self" - a number value." whenever I launch the game via LOVE. I cannot find the error for the life of me. It's halting my game progress, and it's really irritating. It's written in LUA/Love format, can someone help me?

```
local ent = ents.Derive("base")

function ent:load( x, y )
   self:setPos( x, y)
   self.w = 64
   self.h = 64
end

function ent:setSize( w, h )
   self.w = w
   self.h = h
end

function ent:getSize()
   return self.w, self.h;
end

function ent:update(dt)
   self.y = self.y + 32*dt
end

function ent:draw()
   local x, y = self:getPos()
   local w, h = self:getSize()

   love.graphics.setColor(0, 0, 0, 255)
   love.graphics.rectangle("fill", x, y, w, h )
end

return ent;
```

I call the ent:update function in some other files. (Note the above code is stored in another folder which holds all the entity .lua files)

```
function ents:update(dt)
  for i, ent in pairs(ents.objects) do
    if ent.update(dt) then
      ent:update(dt)
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
function love.update(dt)
  xCloud = xCloud + 64*dt
  if xCloud >= (800 + 256) then
    xCloud = 0
  end
  yCloud = yCloud + 32*dt
  if yCloud >= (800 + 256) then
    yCloud = 0
  end
  zCloud = zCloud + 16*dt
  if zCloud >= (800 + 256) then
    zCloud = 0
  end
  ents:update(dt)
end
```

Comment: I'm assuming the error is in one of the `love.graphics.setColor` or `love.graphics.rectangle` calls? Those should presumably either be `love.graphics:setColor(...)` or `love.graphics:rectangle(...)` calls or they should be method (`:`) calls on some instantiated object (possibly `ent` or `self` in that function).

Comment: I changed it and the same error came up. It's referencing line 18, which is the self.y = self.y + 32*dt line. Anything for that?

Comment: That means whatever is calling `ent:update` is calling it as `obj.update(##)` instead of `obj:update(##)`. Which means those `love.graphics` calls may have been correct (I don't know Love2D).

Comment: Alright, I'll poke around that, and update if anything works. Thanks!

Comment: I did notice that my other calls had some variation in using the . and :, could this possible be an issue? I changed a few of them, but it only returned "Attempted to index global "ent" a nil value." I don't believe any of that needs to be changed, but it's possible.

Comment: Is `ents` a global variable? (If not where does the value for it come from in `love.update`?) Yes, calling with `.` and calling with `:` are different and do matter. See [Function Calls](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.8) in the lua manual for the difference "A call v:name(args) is syntactic sugar for v.name(v,args), except that v is evaluated only once."

Comment: ents = {}
    ents.objects = {}
    ents.objpath = "entities/" are in my entities.lua file on the top, alongside my main.lua file. The entities themselves are in a folder with other entities. Would this be creating a problem?

Comment: What function are you expecting `ents:update(dt)` to call? The global `ents` table doesn't have such a function. The `ent` objects do. That's what I was talking about with that comment.

Comment: I'm expecting that    
    ents:update(dt)     
calls the ents:update(dt) function from entities.lua, which is required in my main.lua. That function says: for i, ent in pairs(ents.objects) do
    if ent.update(dt) then
      ent:update(dt), which set in my box.lua file, says that the y should be updated. It returns the "self is a number" error though.

Comment: Ah. I missed that function. Sorry. Yes, the `ent.update(dt)` call in that function is the problem. You need `ent:update(dt)` (which is the same as `ent.update(ent, dt)` and you can see how that differs from `ent.update(dt)`).

Comment: Yes, the game DOES now launch, however after changing the code to:

    function ents:update(dt)
      for i, ent in pairs(ents.objects) do
        if ent:update(dt) then
          ent:update(dt)
      only results in a black screen. Could I be calling it wrong somewhere else too?

Comment: What's the logic in `if ent:update(dt) then ent:update(dt) end`? Why call the function again if it returns true the first time? Also `ent:update` never returns anything so that will *never* run `ent:update` a second time. And I have no idea why your screen might be black other then to say that you clearly did something wrong.

Comment: not entirely sure, but that might be another whole topic, thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "can't index local "self" - a number value."

You defined ent.update like this:

```
function ent:update(dt)
   self.y = self.y + 32*dt
end
```

This is syntax sugar for:

```
function ent.update(self, dt)
   self.y = self.y + 32*dt
end
```

In other words, it requires that you pass self as a first argument.

You then call `ent.update` like this:

```
if ent.update(dt) then
  ent:update(dt)
end
```

Line 2 is correct. Line 1 is not. you're passing a number for self. When it tries to index that, you get "can't index local 'self' - a number value".

Comment: so how exactly can I avoid this? What should I change in the function to make it correct?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your `if ent.update(dt) then` call in the `ents:update` function.

You meant `if ent:update(dt) then` there instead.

The `:` function call syntax is just syntactic sugar so `ent:update(dt)` is just sugar for `ent.update(ent, dt)` (which is clearly different then `ent.update(dt)` and explains the error you were getting).

See [Function Calls](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.8) in the Lua manual for this.

> A call v:name(args) is syntactic sugar for v.name(v,args), except that v is evaluated only once.